# Laravel Redirect Cors Errors

Tags: laravel, redirect, cors

I want to redirect to paypal but give cors error

My code

```
    $payment = resolve(PaypalService::class);

    return $payment->handlePayment($total_price, $currency);
```

PaypalService -> handle Payment code :

```
  public function handlePayment($amount, $currency)
  {
    $order = $this->createOrder($amount, $currency);

    $orderLinks = collect($order->links);

    $approve = $orderLinks->where('rel', 'approve')->first();

    session()->put('approvalId', $order->id);
    return redirect($approve->href);
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epsHZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMkzq.png)

I tried these codes but they didn't work

```
return Redirect::to($approve->href);
return Redirect::away($approve->href);
return redirect()->to($approve->href);
return redirect()->away($approve->href);
```

EDİT:
I find answer

I change ajax to form post and fixed problem. If you use ajax post, return not working